# Round Robin gate-level diagram

Tags: fpga, priority-queue, round-robin

May I know why 'priority' signal is fed back to AND gate input ?
What is the purpose of the AND gate in the picture below ?

From googling, I also found this [article](http://www.rtlery.com/articles/how-design-round-robin-arbiter) , but I am not sure if the AND gate in this article serves the similar purpose.
The article implementation uses some mask vector which seems a bit strange and complicated in terms of hardware resources as well.

[image]

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), not a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is not  a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. (The figure is from a book titled **On-Chip Networks**).

Answer (score 1):

'priority' signal is fed back so that the given priority stays on for multiple cycles since the registers are not conditionally clocked

So, if priority 1 is high and all the grant inputs are low, it will stay high forever.

Well, better wording would be: it is looped back into the AND gate for the purpose of it staying on forever and the AND gate is there to cut it off in case a grant input becomes high